# problema al crear un login con php y mysql con dos roles

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buenos dias veran el problema que tengo es que tengo que hacer un practica de un login con php y mysql con dos diferentes roles, el problema llega cuando me logue con el usuario me manda ala pagina de admin y cuando me logueo con el admin me refresca la pagina creo que podria ser un error con el else if pero no lo llego a ver.
tambien me esta costando bastante porque tengo que cifrar las contraseñas con a al menos en SHA256 o mas y no se si lo estoy haciendo bien y digamos que mis apuntes no son los mejores estaria muy agredecido si me pudieran ayudar les dejo el codigo aqui:

```
<?php 
require_once("conexion.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    $usr = "select * from users where username = '".$username."'";
    $adm = "select * from users where username = '".$username."'";

    $rowsusuario = mysqli_query($connection,$usr);
    $rowsadmin = mysqli_query($connection,$adm);

    $numRowsuser = mysqli_num_rows($rowsusuario);
    $numRowsadmin = mysqli_num_rows($rowsadmin);

    
    
    if($numRowsuser  == 1 ){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowsusuario);
        if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){
            header("Location: pagina.html");
        }
        else{
            echo "Wrong Password";
        }
    }
    if($numRowsadmin  == 1 ){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowsadmin);
        if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){
            header("Location: admin.html");
        }
        else{
            echo "Wrong Password";
        }
    }

    }
    

?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
 
<form  method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: siento si el codigo no esta muy limpio estoy empezando

Comment: Trata de ordenarlo para que no sea dificil de leer... Luego haz un var_dump de $row y muestra que los valores regresados son los que quieres.

Comment: Cómo sabes que un usuario es admin?

Comment: los admin los creo yo en la tabla los usuarios con una pagina de registro

Answer (score 0):

Creo que hay muchas cosas en tu codigo que tienen una logica bastante extraña, te voy a sugerir lo siguiente analizar la logica de lo que hace tu codigo:

**Primero**: Deberia recibir los datos de tu formulario que es un usuario y una clave correcto?

**Segundo**: Ahora debe ver si ese usuario esta en la base de datos.

**Tercero**: verificar que el password es correcto.

**Cuarto y Ultimo**: Ver que tipo de usuario es, si es un usuario comun o un administrador.

Te dejare un ejemplo practico de una funcion que hace basicamente lo descrito en los 4 pasos anteriores

```
    // LOGIN USER
    function login(){
        global $db, $username, $errors, $nombrepag;
    
        // SE RECIBEN LOS VALORES DEL FORM
        $username = e($_POST['username']);
        $password = e($_POST['password']);
    
        // SE VERIFICAN USERNAME Y PASSWORD
        if (empty($username)) {
            array_push($errors, "Su Numero de Usuario o Correo Electronico es Requerido<br>");
        }
        if (empty($password)) {
            array_push($errors, "Su Contraseña de Acceso es Requerida<br>");
        }
    
        // SE VERIFICAN QUE NO EXISTAN ERRORES
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $password = md5($password);
    
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username' OR email='$username') AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    
            if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) { // USUARIO ENCONTRADO
         // VERIFICAR SI ES USER O ADMIN
                $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
    
                $id_usuario = $logged_in_user['id'];
    
    
                if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'admin') {
    
            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Favor Espere";
            $where = $_SESSION['here'];
            if (!empty($where)) {
              header ("Location: $where");
       } else {
              header('location: admin/home.php');
       }
    
        //$origen= $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
        //header('location:'.$origen);
                }
   else if ($logged_in_user['user_type'] == 'user'){
            $_SESSION['user'] = $logged_in_user;
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Favor Espere";
            $where = $_SESSION['here'];
            if (!empty($where)) {
              header ("Location: $where");
       } else {
              header('location: usuario/home.php');
       }
    
                }
            }else {
                array_push($errors, "Combinación incorrecta de nombre de usuario/contraseña");
            }
        }
    }
```

Basicamente podras adaptar esta funcion a tu logica y hacer funcionar tu codigo..!